# Bing maps on Android emulator works but not on device

Tags: android, bing-maps

I've set up the http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/ to try bing maps instead of google maps on Android. Because I was unable to set that up.

I'm able to run Bing maps on my emulator but I'm unable to run it on my device(Galaxy S2).

I have a wifi connection on my phone but I'm still unable to get past the load screen.

I also checked this question but it doesn't solve the problem [Working on Emulator but not on the real Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443167/working-on-emulator-but-not-on-the-real-android-device)

So my code:

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/bingmaps_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="false">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="SplashActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

**Starting Activity copied from the Bing-sdk**

```
package org.bingmaps.app;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.bingmaps.app.R;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.BingMapsView;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.Coordinate;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.EntityClickedListener;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.EntityLayer;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.MapLoadedListener;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.MapMovedListener;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.MapStyles;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.Pushpin;
import org.bingmaps.sdk.PushpinOptions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import android.widget.ZoomButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private BingMapsView bingMapsView;
private GPSManager _GPSManager;
private EntityLayer _gpsLayer;
private ProgressDialog _loadingScreen;

private Activity _baseActivity;

CharSequence[] _dataLayers;
boolean[] _dataLayerSelections;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //OPTION Lock map orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(1);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Initialize();
}

private void Initialize()
{
    _baseActivity = this;
    _GPSManager = new GPSManager((Activity)this, new GPSLocationListener());

    //Add more data layers here
    _dataLayers = new String[] { getString(R.string.traffic)};
    _dataLayerSelections =  new boolean[ _dataLayers.length ];

    _loadingScreen = new ProgressDialog(this);
    _loadingScreen.setCancelable(false);
    _loadingScreen.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.loading) + "...");

    bingMapsView = (BingMapsView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);







    //Create handler to switch out of Splash screen mode
    final Handler viewHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ((ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper)).setDisplayedChild(1);
        }
    };

    //Add a map loaded event handler
    bingMapsView.setMapLoadedListener(new MapLoadedListener() {
        public void onAvailableChecked() {
            // hide splash screen and go to map
            viewHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            //Add GPS layer
            _gpsLayer = new EntityLayer(Constants.DataLayers.GPS);
            bingMapsView.getLayerManager().addLayer(_gpsLayer);
            UpdateGPSPin();
        }
    });

    //Add a entity clicked event handler
    bingMapsView.setEntityClickedListener(new EntityClickedListener() {
        public void onAvailableChecked(String layerName, int entityId) {
            HashMap<String, Object> metadata = bingMapsView.getLayerManager().GetMetadataByID(layerName, entityId);
            DialogLauncher.LaunchEntityDetailsDialog(_baseActivity, metadata);
        }
    });

    //Load the map
    bingMapsView.loadMap(Constants.BingMapsKey, _GPSManager.GetCoordinate(), Constants.DefaultGPSZoomLevel, this.getString(R.string.mapCulture));

    // Create zoom out button functionality
    final ZoomButton zoomOutBtn = (ZoomButton) findViewById(R.id.zoomOutBtn);
    zoomOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bingMapsView.zoomOut();
        }
    });

    // Create zoom button in functionality
    final ZoomButton zoomInBtn = (ZoomButton) findViewById(R.id.zoomInBtn);
    zoomInBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bingMapsView.zoomIn();
        }
    });




}    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //Map Mode menu items
        case R.id.autoBtn:
            bingMapsView.setMapStyle(MapStyles.Auto);
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            return true;
        case R.id.roadBtn:
            bingMapsView.setMapStyle(MapStyles.Road);
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            return true;
        case R.id.aerialBtn:
            bingMapsView.setMapStyle(MapStyles.Aerial);
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            return true;
        case R.id.birdseyeBtn:
            bingMapsView.setMapStyle(MapStyles.Birdseye);
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            return true;
        //More option items
        case R.id.aboutMenuBtn:
            DialogLauncher.LaunchAboutDialog(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.layersMenuBtn:
            DialogLauncher.LaunchLayersDialog(this, bingMapsView, _dataLayers, _dataLayerSelections);
            return true;
        case R.id.clearMapMenuBtn:
            bingMapsView.getLayerManager().clearLayer(null);

            //unselect all layers
            for(int i=0;i<_dataLayerSelections.length;i++){
                _dataLayerSelections[i] = false;
            }

            //re-add GPS layer
            bingMapsView.getLayerManager().clearLayer(Constants.DataLayers.GPS);
            UpdateGPSPin();
            return true;
        //GPS Menu Item
        case R.id.gpsMenuBtn:
            Coordinate coord = _GPSManager.GetCoordinate();

            if(coord != null){
                //Center on users GPS location
                bingMapsView.setCenterAndZoom(coord, Constants.DefaultGPSZoomLevel);
            }
            return true;
        //Search Menu Item
        case R.id.searchMenuBtn:
            DialogLauncher.LaunchSearchDialog(this, bingMapsView, loadingScreenHandler);
            return true;    
        //Directions Menu Item
        case R.id.directionsMenuBtn:
            DialogLauncher.LaunchDirectionsDialog(this, bingMapsView, loadingScreenHandler);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void UpdateGPSPin(){        
    PushpinOptions opt = new PushpinOptions();
    opt.Icon = Constants.PushpinIcons.GPS;
    Pushpin p = new Pushpin(_GPSManager.GetCoordinate(), opt);
    if (p.Location != null) {       
        _gpsLayer.clear();
        _gpsLayer.add(p);
        _gpsLayer.updateLayer();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private final MapMovedListener mapMovedListener = new MapMovedListener() {
    public void onAvailableChecked() {
        //OPTION Add logic to Update Layers here. 
        //This will update data layers when the map is moved.
    }
};

/**
 * Handler for loading Screen
 */
protected Handler loadingScreenHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.arg1 == 0) {
            _loadingScreen.hide();
        } else {
            _loadingScreen.show();
        }
    }
};

public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        UpdateGPSPin();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }   
}
}
```

ERRORS from LOGCAT: non

Comment: What is your emulator's SDK? Try changing it to the later ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bing maps for android does not work for android versions 3.0 and higher