# Bing Map working on android emulator but not on android devices

Tags: android, bing-maps

Bing maps working properly on emulator but not on an actual android device, [Bing maps on Android emulator works but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570495/bing-maps-on-android-emulator-works-but-not-on-device) , I referred this question but I'm unable to get any solution. Please suggest how can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing Maps Android SDK from codeplex is deprecated. The best way to develop Bing Maps apps on Android is to use the Bing Maps V7 AJAX control as described here:
http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/06/28/cross-platform-development-with-bing-maps-and-phonegap.aspx
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cross-Platform-Bing-Maps-e96600d5

Also take a look at Chapter 11 of my free ebook on creating location intelligent apps with Bing Maps: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/

Comment: Thanks for reply, will try on Cross platform and integrate it, but why bing has not updated their api for native android platform

Comment: Bing is a Microsoft development API. The focus in the past has been on Microsoft platforms.